# Unresolved compilation problem_FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, selenium

**Problem:**

- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
  FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved to a type

**Versions of software Applications installed:**

- Selenium WebDriver: 3.8.0
- Java 9.0.1
- Eclipse (IDE)

**WebDrivers installed:**

- geckodriver

**Code As Follows:**

```
package test_package_1;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Browser_Invocation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\steph\\AppData\\Local\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    }

}
```

**Analysis:**

- In my research on trying to fix this issue, I have run across some posts that have referenced two different solutions.

  1. Validate whether the Selenium version is compatible.
  2. Ensure that the JAR files have been added at the project level.
- I have added all the JAR files that I am aware of at the project level but I am still unsure if I have the right Selenium file.

[Project Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3f7f.png)

Comment: what is the version of firefox installed ? and even the property of geckodriver is incorrect

Comment: Can you update the question with the entire error stack trace for an analysis? Additionally provide the version info of all the binaries you are using and possibly the list/snapshot of the _JAR_ files you have added.

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar, which part of the System.setProperty of geckodriver is incorrect?

Comment: @DebanjanB, I have added a Project Error screen shot to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

For basic operations you just need to add `selenium-server-standalone.jar` file to your project. You ll get it on seleniums's official website. Your `geckodriver` property should be as the below one:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\Users\\steph\\AppData\\Local\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Also ensure that your `firefox` version is below `48.0` or else your scripts won't run.

Comment: thank you so much for your assistance.  I made the following changes you mentioned but I am still getting the error message. I have posted the details below.

Answer (score 0):

This issue says that you missed a jar to add, this jar is not inside the lib folder you can find it immediately outside the lib folder named : **client-combined-3.0.1-nodeps.jar**

Comment: The only two JAR files that reside outside the lib folder are: client-combined-3.8.0 and client-combined-3.8.0-sources.

Answer (score 0):

The following JAR files have been added to my project:
[JAR Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN51l.png)